# Уведомление JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

дайте пожалуйста пример уведомления.
Мне нужно чтобы с право в нижнем углу появлялись боксы с текстом и пропадали через 3 секунды.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно [от сюда](https://ned.im/noty/#/)

```js
Noty.overrideDefaults({
    layout   : 'bottomRight',
    theme: 'sunset',
    timeout: 3000,
});

new Noty({
    
    text: 'Some notification text',
    
}).show();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noty/3.1.4/noty.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noty/3.1.4/noty.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо! а как дизайн свой сделать?

Comment: `container: '.custom-container'` Дизайн не работает, так надо узучать глубже.Отметьте как принятый ответ.

Comment: [Темы дезайна](https://ned.im/noty/#/themes)